# Adding Sentry to AWS Lambda, how do I run it locally?

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, promise, sentry

I have created an AWS Lambda in node that I can run locally like so:

```
exports.handler = async function () {
    return await myFunction();
}
    
exports.handler();
```

I would like to add Sentry to this [and have followed the instructions here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/aws-lambda/), leaving me with the following:

```
const Sentry = require("@sentry/serverless");

Sentry.AWSLambda.init({
    dsn: "https://myURL.com",

    // We recommend adjusting this value in production, or using tracesSampler
    // for finer control
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});

exports.handler = Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(async (event, context) => {
    return await myFunction();
});


exports.handler();
```

However this unfortunately will no longer run with the following error (it does however actually send to Sentry).

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop')
```

I *suspect* that it's because of the extra parameters `event` & `context`, however I've no idea how to provide them when I'm running locally.

Any tips / suggestions of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop')

The [`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) property is part of the `context` object. It defines Lambda behavior in relation to callbacks.

Since you’re using `Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(async (event, context)...`, it seems to be trying to read an `undefined` context object. This will obviously fail.

Sentry doesn't require you to always have an event and/or context object.

If you don’t use them, don’t pass them through.

This should work for *local development*:

```js
exports.handler = Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(async () => {
    return await myFunction();
});

exports.handler();
```

---

However, I would recommend keeping the handler signature you currently have - `Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(async (event, context)...` if you are going to be executing this function in the cloud, or need a more realistic local environment.

This is so that Sentry can pull as much information as possible.

---

When Lambda invokes your function handler, the Lambda runtime passes two arguments to the function handler:

- `event`
- `context`

The [event object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-event) contains information from the invoker. In the simplest way possible, this is the input to your Lambda.

The [context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) is passed to your function by Lambda at runtime. The context object provides information about the invocation, function, and runtime environment.

Based on the [Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/aws-lambda/#behavior),

> The Issue reports automatically include:
>
> - A link to the cloudwatch logs
> - Function details
> - sys.argv for the function
> - AWS Request ID
> - Function execution time
> - Function version

Items here like the request ID, execution time, function version etc. will be part of the context object.

With no context being accepted by your handler and passed through to the `wrapHandler` function, your issue reports will be incomplete.

---

The best setup will closely align the local execution of your Lambda function with its execution in the cloud, by creating a mock `context` object and passing it through when invoking your Lambda function manually.

You may only need to pass a subset of these through e.g. `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` for it to work as a minimum, but I've listed all the values here (excluding `identity` and `clientContext` which are for mobile apps) for the sake of completeness.

This should work:

```js
const context = {
    getRemainingTimeInMillis: function() { return 5000; },
    
    functionName: 'yourFunctionName',
    functionVersion: '1.0',
    invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:yourFunctionName',
    memoryLimitInMB: '128',
    awsRequestId: 'id-1234567890',
    logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/yourFunctionName',
    logStreamName: '2023/09/14/[$LATEST]1234',
    callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
};

exports.handler = Sentry.AWSLambda.wrapHandler(async (event, context) => {
    return await myFunction();
});

exports.handler(undefined, context);
```

---

`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` can be set to `true` or `false` for your mocked context.

In the Node.js runtime, a third argument in addition to the event and context - a callback object - is also supported.

Originally, AWS Lambda only supported the callback pattern for managing asynchronous operations in JavaScript. This is why the callback parameter exists.

However, on 30th May 2017, native support for the async/await syntax was introduced with Node.js v8. Subsequently, AWS Lambda announced its support for the Node.js 8.10 runtime on [2nd April 2018](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/#:%7E:text=The%20Lambda%20programming%20model%20for%20Node.js%208.10%20now%20supports%20defining%20a%20function%20handler%20using%20the%20async/await%20pattern.), which also included support for the async/await pattern for function handlers.

This made the callback function redundant for asynchronous Lambdas.

While you might still see the callback object in older Lambda functions, it’s no longer necessary. The current recommended format for a Node.js function handler includes only the event and context arguments, like other runtimes.

Given that you’re not using a callback, locally or for cloud executions of your lambda, setting this property to either `true` or `false` won’t make any difference.